# Safari failed to calculate height with flexbox. Elements overlap

Tags: google-chrome, safari, flexbox, angular-material

Using flexbox from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/

On Safari if i resize my browser on less than 600px it fails to calculate element's height and they overlap each other.

You can see the bug on my website :

1. Go : http://www.compareagences.com/user/funnel/attentes
2. Resize Safari (Mac. Safari 8.0.6) on less than 600px
3. Safari failed to calculate height. (Flex)

This bug is also on Chrome for iPhone... (But not on Android)!

Image :
[Flexbox and Safari : Bug on element's height. Overlaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zquwG.png)

EDIT : 
i have switched 
`<div flex="25" flex="100">` to `<div flex-gt-sm="25">`
and it's working....
Still it's a weird difference between browser...